# Twilio Programmable Voice isn't working

Tags: objective-c, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

When i try to pass param from my application using `[TwilioVoice Call]` method i am not able to get those param on twiML application. but when i try to pass same data from **POSTMAN** with FormData its working fine and also successfully able to create call.

Would you please help me how can i use param passed from my iOS application into twiML

**TwiML Application in PHP :**

```
<?php
/*
 * Makes a call to the specified client using the Twilio REST API.
 */
include('./vendor/autoload.php');
include('./config.php');
$to = isset($_GET["to"]) ? $_GET["to"] : "";
if (!isset($to) || empty($to)) {
    $to = isset($POST["to"]) ? $_POST["to"] : "";
}
$from = isset($_GET["from"]) ? $_GET["from"] : "";
if (!isset($from) || empty($from)) {
    $from = isset($POST["from"]) ? $_POST["from"] : "";
}

use Twilio\Twiml;
$response = new Twiml();
$dial = $response->dial(['callerId' => $from]);
$dial->client($to);
echo $response;
```

**iOS Objective-C :**

```
self.call = [TwilioVoice call:[self fetchAccessToken]
                           params:@{@"to": @"1",@"from":@"2"}
                             uuid:uuid
                         delegate:self];
```

**Twilio Error Log when i try to pass param from iOS**

> Warning - 13224 Dial: Twilio does not support calling this number or the number is invalid

[image]

**Reference TwiML Application Code**

https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-server-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [12100 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12100) comes from Twilio not being able to parse the TwiML returned from your server. In this case, it is because your PHP is not returning TwiML, it's trying to [make a call using the REST API](http://twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls).

It should return a [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with a nested [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client). You can build this up using the helper library too. Try changing your code to this:

```
<?php
    include('./vendor/autoload.php');
    include('./config.php');

    $to = isset($_REQUEST["To"]) ? $_REQUEST["To"] : "";
    $to = str_replace("client:", "", $to);

    $from = isset($_REQUEST["From"]) ? $_REQUEST["From"] : "";

    use Twilio\Twiml;

    $response = new Twiml();
    $dial = $response->dial(['callerId' => $from]);
    $dial->client($to);

    echo $response;
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have tried same but still same error, take a look at my updated code above.

Comment: Are you able to make a request to your PHP application and see what XML is being returned? That might help point to where the error is.

Comment: Bah, I've just seen my error. Hold on, need to update the code in the answer.

Comment: Ok, corrected it. It was around the `$dial`. Take another look and let me know if that works.

Comment: Got another error please take look i have added more detail logs so that will help find issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. The issue is that the parameters being sent are `To` and `From`, but you are trying to extract `to` and `from`. Parameters are case sensitive. So if you update your PHP to use `To` and `From` it should work. You can use `$_REQUEST` rather than checking for `$_GET` and `$_POST` too. I'll update my answer too.

Comment: thanks for the quick response i got this error "Warning - 13224 Dial: Twilio does not support calling this number or the number is invalid". updated my question for the same

Comment: Ah, I should have seen this coming. You don't need the `client:` prefix inside the `<Client>`. Try string replacing `"client:"` from `$to`. I'll update my answer again too.

Comment: thank you so much for the help, now i am successfully able to connect call and its really working fine, twilio dashboard still show this error "Error - 52131
Invalid APNs credentials" even push notification is working well

Comment: Sounds like you're sorted then. Great to hear! If you continue to have a problem with APNS credentials then do ask another question and we can try to get to the bottom of that.

Comment: yes sure thank you so much for the kind of information

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  In the name you have to pass name of the user(any thing you want)

Step 2.  You need to generate token using 3 parameters

Step 3.  You need to create object of VoiceGrant

Step 4.  You need to pass Id

Step 5.  You need to set PUSH notification Id generate from twilio

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
            //$PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID = 'CRaf1a66dd4a7656876e16c7820ef5c01e';
             $outgoingApplicationSid = 'APf9b1b789ba690b8789d95a42511f2018';
              // choose a random username for the connecting user
             $identity = $name;
             // Create access token, which we will serialize and send to the client


             $token = new AccessToken(
             $this->twilioAccountSid,
             $this->twilioApiKey,
             $this->twilioApiSecret,
             3600,
             $identity
              );
          //     $chatGrant = new ChatGrant( $pushCredentialSid= "CRaf1a66dd4a7656876e16c7820ef5c01e");
          //
          // print_r($chatGrant);die;
             // Create Chat grant
             // $voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant($serviceSid = 'IS840a7e5f64634ab6bf179c3f8b0adfc4',$pushCredentialSid = 'CRaf1a66dd4a7656876e16c7820ef5c01e');
             $voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant();
             $voiceGrant->setOutgoingApplicationSid($outgoingApplicationSid);

             // Optional: add to allow incoming calls
             $voiceGrant->setIncomingAllow(true);

             $voiceGrant->setPushCredentialSid('CRaf1a66dd4a7656876e16c7820ef5c01e');


             // Add grant to token
             $token->addGrant($voiceGrant);

             // render token to string
            $voice_token = $token->toJWT();
             if($voice_token){
                $data['token'] = $voice_token;
                 $this->response = array('status'=>1,'data'=>$data);
             }else{
                 $this->response = array('status'=>0,'message'=>'Not found');
             }
```

Comment: Please check steps